# Scrapy trying to crawl information internal links of webpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl the page [JobStreet](https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?area=1&option=1&specialization=191%2C192%2C193&job-source=1%2C64&classified=1&job-posted=0&sort=1&order=0&pg=1&src=16&srcr=12&ojs=3)

I'm able to crawl the information on the main page but my issue comes when i'm trying to crawl the internal links of the page for example the first posting [here](https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job/software-developer-java-agile-5997516?fr=J&src=16&srcr=12)

This is a snippet of my code:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy import Item, Field

class IT(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'IT'

    allowed_domains = ["www.jobstreet.com.sg"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?key=&specialization=191%2C192%2C193&area=&salary=&ojs=3&src=12',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'/en/job/*.'], restrict_xpaths=('//*[(@class = "position-title-link")]',)), callback='parse_info', follow=True)
    )


    def parse_info(self, response):

        self.logger.info('response.url=%s' % response.url)
```

Not able to get any sort of response from parse_info.

Answer (score 3):

You may change

```
scrapy.Spider
```

to

```
CrawlSpider
```

Answer (score 0):

you change

```
scrapy.Spider
```

to

```
CrawlSpider
```

but some time when you are using callback at first rule it does not work.
Than you may use it.

```
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        list(self.parse_info(response))
```